# How does a browser remember the scroll state?

Tags: browser

For example you are visiting a page and scrolled down half way through and then you refresh the page the browser remembers your scroll state and loads the page at exactly the same spot where you were viewing it.

I think the same thing happens when you hit the back button.

Comment: Why would you think this is strange or difficult?  In any case, this isn't answerable as it depends on the particular browser's implementation details.

Comment: People don't always ask questions because they find something strange or difficult. People also ask questions because they find a certain phenomenon interesting, and curiosity's in our human nature. I find it interesting because it was programmed by programmers and I am a programmer. The same way a bridge engineer finds certain elements of a bridge interesting and asks other engineers about it.

Comment: @StevenBurnap sometimes being realistic is a very good quality. But why not try doing something impossible, undoable and strange? After all the Universe is a place where everything is possible. But the most important thing is to always do what you WANT, not what you're supposed to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scroll bar has a numeric position associated with it.  More specifically, *it's a get/set property on the scroll bar object.*  When you navigate to another page, the browser stores the number corresponding to the current scroll bar position with the page URL.  When you navigate back to that page, the browser recalls the scroll bar position.  That's all.

This technique is not unique to browsers; generally you can do the same thing in any UI framework that has windows and scroll bars.

Comment: So, it is answerable and the answer is not that difficult to understand. Thank you! You're awesome